# IOS buy, erase phone, detect previously purchased

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, new-operator, reset

I got most of IAP purchase working, using user defaults etc

But supposing a user buys an app, then erases or updates to a new phone.

Then reinstalls the app.

How do I detect that the user has previously purchased the app?

Answer (score 0):

That is what restore functionality is for. See the Restore section of:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases

Comment: I know about restoring purchases, but if the user has never bought the app before then then:     StoreObserver.shared.restore()

Comment: You said “the user has previously purchased the app”. That is the problem that restore solves.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways:

1. If you store some purchase indicator in the app keychain, it will be present when the app is re-installed.  If you are doing subscriptions also include an expiration date you can check if a subscription is possibly out of date.
2. If you send the app receipt up to Apple, it will always give you back the most current purchase data - which includes any prior purchases. So on first launch, always send the receipt up to Apple to see if you might want to automatically restore a purchase made previously.  Note that sometimes an application receipt will not be present immediately after install (although it should always be there), which is why you also need to allow for option 3.
3. There is also a `SKPaymentQueue’s restoreCompletedTransactions()` call you can make to basically replay previous purchase transactions.  This is something you should wire to a button somewhere in your UI - Apple requires that.  It's not something you want to automatically call as it can prompt for the user to enter their iTunes account password, so you should not rely on this method to restore purchases automatically, but it is good to have in place as a backup for the user.